# Why cannot resolve file with javascript, webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bazel

Is a webpack compile producing an `app.bundle.js` of `77 bytes` somewhat normal? Also, it says `Can't resolve 'bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/penpalling_web/index.js' in '/private/var/tmp/_bazel_kevin/d3141ad1e6fcae83ac4bb72493c727e5/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/31/execroot/my_wksp'`, but that file actually exists, I don't know why it can't resolve it ..

```
 + bazel-out/host/bin/external/npm/webpack-cli/bin/webpack-cli.sh.runfiles/nodejs_darwin_amd64/bin/nodejs/bin/node --preserve-symlinks --require ./bazel-out/host/bin/external/npm/webpack-cli/bin/webpack-cli.sh.runfiles/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/node/node_patches.js node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/penpalling_web/index.js --config penpalling_web/webpack.config.js -o bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/penpalling_web/app.bundle.js  
[webpack-cli] Compilation finished
asset app.bundle.js 77 bytes [compared for emit] (name: main)

ERROR in main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/penpalling_web/index.js' in '/private/var/tmp/_bazel_kevin/d3141ad1e6fcae83ac4bb72493c727e5/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/31/execroot/my_wksp'

webpack 5.4.0 compiled with 1 error in 71 ms
+ RESULT=1
```

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Tried  keeing only two extensions. However the issue is not resolved.

 resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx']
    },